# checking whether a path has a title in svg with d3

Tags: jquery, svg, d3.js

I have a d3 presentation showing a globe of the world. When I mouse over a country, I want the code to append a title IF it doesn't already have a title. Otherwise, the code appends title after title to the same path. How do I check whether a path has a title?

```
function pathOver(d) {
        var thisID = d.properties.id;
        if (!d3.select('path#' +thisID).attr('title')) { //this doesn't work
            d3.select('path#' +thisID).append('title').text(function(d){return d.properties.name});
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the title and see if the selection is empty:

```
if(d3.select('path#' + thisID).selectAll('title').empty()) {
  d3.select('path#' +thisID).append('title').text(function(d){return d.properties.name});
}
```